# JAVA - Is it possible to detect if a document contains malicious script?

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, xss

I am working on a functionality wherein user can upload documents [PDF, JPG, PNG, GIF] in system. I am validating the documents for their size, type, name and limit on number of documents uploaded.
I am using Apache tika library to detect type of a document based on few bytes from file. So if I have a file `abc.js` and I rename it to `abc.pdf`, API will not accept it.
However, script can be added in an Image after valid bytes. In that scenario, type comes as one of accepted file types.
Is there a way to parse and inspect actual document content and examine it for malicious content such as javasscript/scripting language payloads?

TIA

Comment: You can run a virus scanner separately. The rest is just uncertainty. Images (svg), PDFs, word docs, ppt, all can be scripted. And then there are exploits of buffer overflow.

Comment: Hi , can you tell me how are you validating the document?I have similar requirement where if the pdf contains js code then API must not accept that file

Answer (score 0):

you can read file by type , if read file successful than file not contain any malicious script but if read file has error than file is invalid:

```
    if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("png") || fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("JPG")){
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(filePath);
        try {
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(file);
            if(image == null){
                //file invalid
            }
            //file valid
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //file invalid
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")){
        try {
            org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument document = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(new java.io.File(filePath);
            if(document == null){
                //file invalid
            }
            //file valid
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //file invalid
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        //file invalid
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't get this. How can we so sure that the file doesn't contain any malicious script if it has been read successfully?

Comment: Hey Raju, did you manage to code this functionality? I'm in the same situation now.